LM2576HVSX12NOPB blew up on 48V 10A PSU input
this is my schematic project for BLDC controller. the design have dc converter, mcu and gate driver. the dc converter is required to power the mcu and driver with 12 V and 5V. the problem is my dc converter fail when connected with 48V 10A Chinese PSU. the burnt always shown on pin 1 LM2576HV (Vin). I am also comparing the result with dc generator 38V 0.1 A and get the desired value. but when using this 48V 10A psu my lm2576HV got blew up
this psu i bought from local supllier, the rating said that dc ouput is 48V 10A. i wonder that this current rating is the reason my lm2576HV blew up or my schematic design is fail 

Figure 8-6 in the datasheet recommends 680 µH as L1 for this context. Do you test this on a PCB or on a breadboard? 10 kohm as gate resistors for IRFP260 will allow PWM below 100 Hz only, very unusual. R14, 15, 16 and C22, 23, 24 form a 16 Hz low pass filter. This will be an issue if you need more than 10 rpm.

yes, i test this on pcb. thanks for checking the datasheet, i will correct L1 later.  how about the correct curent rating for L1? i dont find it on datasheet. as for the resistor,  i havent calculate the gate resistor yet. how this gate resistor affect the irfp460 freq?
